# How to process items in parallel and then merge the results?

Tags: c#, concurrency, merge, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am confronted with the following problem:

I have a a data stream of `Foo` objects and stream those objects to several concurrent in-process tasks/threads which in turn process the objects and output `FooResult` objects. Each `FooResult` contains among othermembers the same `Foo` that was used in the creation of a `FooResult`. However, not every `Foo` necessarily creates a `FooResult`.

My problem is that I want to pass on from this whole process a wrapping object that contains the original `Foo` and potentially all, if any, `FooResult` objects that may have been created from a `Foo` within the concurrent tasks.

Note: I currently use TPL Dataflow, whereas each concurrent process happens within an `ActionBlock<Foo>` which is linked to from a `BroadCastBlock<Foo>`. It uses `SendAsync()` to a target dataflow block to send potentially created `FooResult`. Obviously the concurrent data flow blocks produce `FooResult` at unpredictable times which is what I currently struggle with. I do not seem to be able to figure out how many `FooResult` were created in all `ActionBlock<Foo>` together so that I can bundle them up with the originating `Foo` and pass it on as a wrapping object.

In Pseudo code it currently looks as follows:

```
BroadCastBlock<Foo> broadCastBlock;
ActionBlock<Foo> aBlock1;
ActionBlock<Foo> aBlock2; 
ActionBlock<FooResult> targetBlock;
broadCastBlock.LinkTo(aBlock1); broadCastBlock.LinkTo(aBlock2);

aBlock1 = new ActionBlock<Foo>(foo =>
{
    //do something here. Sometimes create a FooResult. If then
    targetBlock.SendAsync(fooResult);
});

//similar for aBlock2
```

However, the problem with the current code is that the targetBlock potentially does not receive anything if a `Foo` did not produce a single `FooResult` in any of the action blocks. Also, it could be that targetBlock receives 2 `FooResult` objects because each action block produced a `FooResult`.

What I want is that the targetBlock receives a wrapping object that contains each `Foo` and if `FooResult` objects were created then also a collection of `FooResult`.

Any ideas what I could do to make the solution work in the way described? It does not have to peruse TPL Dataflow but it would be neat if it did.

**UPDATE: The following is what I got through the implementation of JoinBlock as suggested by svick. I am not gonna use it (unless it can be tweaked performance wise), because it is extremely slow to run, I get to about 89000 items (and thats only int value types) per second.**

```
public class Test
{
    private BroadcastBlock<int> broadCastBlock;
    private TransformBlock<int, int> transformBlock1;
    private TransformBlock<int, int> transformBlock2;
    private JoinBlock<int, int, int> joinBlock;
    private ActionBlock<Tuple<int, int, int>> processorBlock;

    public Test()
    {
        broadCastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            });

        transformBlock1 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

        transformBlock2 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

        joinBlock = new JoinBlock<int, int, int>();

        processorBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, int, int>>(tuple =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("original value: " + tuple.Item1 + "tfb1: " + tuple.Item2 + "tfb2: " + tuple.Item3);
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded });

        //Linking
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock1.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock2.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target3, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        joinBlock.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        const int numElements = 1000000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numElements; i++)
        {
            broadCastBlock.Post(i);
        }

        ////mark completion
        broadCastBlock.Complete();

        processorBlock.Completion.Wait();

        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Time it took: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " - items processed per second: " + numElements / watch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Update of the code to reflect suggestions:**

```
public Test()
    {
        broadCastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            });

        transformBlock1 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            });

        transformBlock2 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(i =>
            {
                return i;
            });

        joinBlock = new JoinBlock<int, int>();

        processorBlock = new ActionBlock<Tuple<int, int>>(tuple =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("tfb1: " + tuple.Item1 + "tfb2: " + tuple.Item2);
            });

        //Linking
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock1, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        broadCastBlock.LinkTo(transformBlock2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock1.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target1);
        transformBlock2.LinkTo(joinBlock.Target2);
        joinBlock.LinkTo(processorBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        const int numElements = 1000000;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numElements; i++)
        {
            broadCastBlock.Post(i);
        }

        ////mark completion
        broadCastBlock.Complete();
        Task.WhenAll(transformBlock1.Completion, transformBlock2.Completion).ContinueWith(_ => joinBlock.Complete());


        processorBlock.Completion.Wait();

        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Time it took: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " - items processed per second: " + numElements / watch.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` is sketchy. Essentially you command the TPL Dataflow to process all the posted items concurrently. This can only be done by creating a `Task` for each item, and scheduling it on the `ThreadPool`. So you are creating a huge overhead in terms of allocated space, and a big scheduling burden for the `ThreadPool`. Eventually you are going to be throttled implicitly by the availability of threads in the `ThreadPool`, because there is no way that it has a million threads available. Is short: don't do this, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two ways to solve this:

1. Use [`JoinBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160286.aspx). Your broadcast block, and both worker blocks will each send to one target of the join block. If a worker block doesn't have any results, it will give it `null` instead (or some other special value). Your worker blocks will need to change to `TranformBlock<Foo, FooResult>`, because using `ActionBlock` the way you do doesn't guarantee ordering (at least not when you set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`), `TransformBlock` does.

   The result of the `JoinBlock` would be a `Tuple<Foo, FooResult, FooResult>`, where any or both of the `FooResult`s can be `null`.

   Although I'm not sure I like that this solution relies heavily on correct ordering of items, that seems fragile to me.
2. Use some other object for synchronization. That object will be then responsible for sending the result forward, when all blocks are done with a certain item. This is similar to the `NotificationWrapper` suggested by Mario in his answer.

   You could use `TaskCompletionSource` and `Task.WhenAll()` to take care of synchronization in this case.

Comment: I added an implementation using JoinBlock as part of my question (see "Update"). Does that look about right? It seems to run correctly, but it is extremely slow, about 89k items per second. If I cannot improve on the performance then I need to think of a different solution. Any ideas or you think this is as good as it gets?

Comment: On my computer your code gives me ~350-400k/s. And if I remove the `JoinBlock`, so it's broadcast → transform1 → action1 and broadcast → transform2 → action2, I get about the same performance. So I don't think the `JoinBlock` slows you down by much.

Comment: Thanks, the above code gets me to 580k elements per second. Unfortunately not enough for my purposes. I need to over-think all of it, potentially I will remove concurrency as part of this specific part of the project, basically not using TPL Dataflow, no broadcast block, but rather feed the messages into different instances in round-robin type of fashion and collecting results and then passing them on. But need to performance profile to make a final decision. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I am learning TPL Dataflow at this time and got the same problem with merging results using JoinBlocks. So I envision a target BufferBlock to store all results, then having it conditionally linked (`LinkTo` with predicates) to specifics Blocks that will do the merge. Could this be a acceptable third way ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the issue:

```
lock foo
work on foo
if foo has not triggered sending a result
and fooResult exists
   send fooResult
   remember in foo that result has already been sent
unlock foo
```

***Update after comment of OP***

So push foo into your BroadCastBlock

```
BroadCastBlock<Foo> bcb = new BroadCastBlock<Foo>(foo);
...

if ( aBlock1.HasResult ) 
{
    bcb.Add( aBlock1.Result );
}

if ( aBlock2.HasResult ) 
{
    bcb.Add( aBlock2.Result );
}
```

And now you can query bcb for what is present and send what needed (or just send the bcb).

***Update (after even more discussion in comments)***

```
class NotificationWrapper<TSource, TResult>
{
   private readonly TSource originalSource;

   private Queue<TResult> resultsGenerated = new Queue<TResult>()

   private int workerCount = 0;

   public NotificationWrapper<TSource, TResult>( TSource originalSource, int workerCount )
   {
       this.originalSource = originalSource;
       this.workerCount = workerCount;
   }

   public void NotifyActionDone()
   {
       lock( this )
       {
          --workerCount;
          if ( 0 == workerCount )
          {
             //do my sending
             send( originalSource, resultsGenerated );
          }
       }
   }

    public void NotifyActionDone( TResult result )
    {
        lock ( this )
        {
            resultsGenerated.push( result );
            NotifyActionDone();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the calling Code:

```
NotificationWrapper<Foo, Fooresult> notificationWrapper = new NotificationWrapper<Foo, Fooresult>( foo, 2 );
ActionBlock<Foo> ab1 = new ActionBlock<Foo>( foo, notificationWrapper );
ActionBlock<Foo> ab2 = new ActionBlock<Foo>( foo, notificationWrapper );
```

And the ActionBlock needs to be changed to either call `NotifyActionDone()` or `NotifyActoinDone( Fooresult )` once it completed its calculation.

Comment: hmm, not absolutely correct (if I understand you correctly): stream foo into each actionblock -> have actionblock produce a fooResult or nothing (though I could always have it pass on a foo and if a fooResult was created then attach it) -> wait until I know each foo was processed within the actionBlocks -> send a wrapping object that contains the original foo and potentially created fooResults.

Comment: I am afraid it does not really solve the problem. First of all the action blocks may not have generated a result yet at the time of hasResult query because the processing time may take longer not because no fooResult was generated. Secondly, your solution does not guarantee that each result will refer to the same foo that was streamed into the blocks. I only want to bundle results that refer to identical foo objects.

Comment: If you create a new BroadCastBLock for every new foo then it will. Do you know how many action blocks there are?

Comment: yes I do know how many action blocks there are, and as mentioned in my question I consider always outputting a wrapping object as result from each action block, which is the foo that was streamed in plus a fooResult in case it was generated. I do not see any sense in creating new BroadcastBlocks for each foo. It already fails at the overhead this would create. I deal with millions of foo objects per second. There must be a better solution, at least creating more than one broadcast block is a no go for me.

Comment: Thanks for your code but it seems your code still does not assure results of the action blocks OF THE SAME Foo instance end up in the same NotificationWrapper object. It may even happen that 2 results of the same actionblock of different Foos end up in the same wrapper object. Also, I guess your code above pertains to a NotificationWrapper class object, correct? The class decoration is missing. Also, your ActionBlock instantiation is incorrect and would not even compile. Sorry but I am afraid the answer is more complex.